# How to sort list on multiple properties in one line of code in Linq

Tags: c#, linq, sorting

I want to sort list on on multiple properties. I know I can use

```
List<Order> l = source.OrderBy(c=> c.Property1).ThenBy(c=> c.Property2).ToList();
```

However, it is for ascending only. If I want to sort list for descending, I need another code

```
List<Order> l = source.OrderByDescending(c=> c.Property1).ThenByDescending(c=> c.Property2).ToList();
```

And if I want to sort property1 for ascending and property2 for descending, I have to use

```
List<Order> l = source.OrderBy(c=> c.Property1).ThenByDescending(c=> c.Property2).ToList();
```

For sort on 2 properties, I need 4 different codes and on 3 properties, I need 9 different codes. There is not good. I want to know if there is a way to do the sorting in one code. Thanks.

Comment: that is the best way to do it...

Comment: Do you mean you want the direction of sort to be parameterised, so that the same code can sort in any combination of ascending and descending depending on the parameters?

Comment: I think linq should provide a way to do sort like: OrderBy(c=> c.Property1, sortOrder).ThenBy(c=> c.Property2, sortOrder). It is simple and straight. Is there something like that in Linq?

Comment: `For sort on 2 properties, I need 4 different codes` - I mean, yeah, if you're hard coding each possible combination. Just like reading 100 elements from an array *can* take 100 lines of code. Generalize your requirement, then write a small method which will decide which order method to call, and which property to call it on.

Comment: @Stuart Whitehouse, yes, I want to sort parameterised like, OrderBy(c=> c.Property1, sortOrder).ThenBy(c=> c.Property2, sortOrder), where sortOrder is bool. True means ascending and false means descending. It is simple and straight. I think Linq should have something like that.

Comment: Best way to sort is to create an extension with an expression parameter for both order by ascending and descending which would be nice,

Comment: @Ephraim, can you elaborate on your idea?

Comment: @user585440 https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/bb383977.aspx - You can write your own extension methods, so that you can 'extend' LINQ.

Comment: @Rob, I know extension methods but I am not sure how to pass lamda expression like c=> c.Property1 to method.

Comment: @user585440 Simply copy the `OrderBy` definition. In this case it would be: `public static IOrderedQueryable<TSource> OrderBy<TSource, TKey>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, Expression<Func<TSource, TKey>> keySelector, bool ascending)`.

Comment: @Rob, you can post it as answer

Answer (score 2):

The [System.Linq.Dynamic](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic/) package provides an OrderBy extension method that just takes a string:

```
using System.Linq.Dynamic;
//...    

var l = source.OrderBy("Property1 ascending, Property2 descending").ToList();
```

You can use it to build elaborate expressions on the fly:

```
string orderByClause = string.Format("Property1 {0}, Property2 {1}", "ascending", "descending");
var l = source.OrderBy(orderByClause).ToList();
```

See [IQueryable Extension Methods](https://github.com/kahanu/System.Linq.Dynamic/wiki/Dynamic-Expressions#iqueryable-extension-methods) for more info in the project Wiki

Answer (score 1):

You can write your own LINQ extension to determine which method to pick. For example:

```
public static class LinqExtensions
{
    public static IOrderedQueryable<TSource> OrderBy<TSource, TKey>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, Expression<Func<TSource, TKey>> keySelector, bool ascending)
    {
        return ascending ? source.OrderBy(keySelector) : source.OrderByDescending(keySelector);
    }
}
```

And then you can use it like this:

```
source.OrderBy(a => a.Id, ascending);
```

Comment: How to do source.OrderBy(a => a.Id, ascending).ThenBy(c=> c.name, descending)? I know sort on different properties must be done at same time.

Comment: @user585440 You'd simply copy the above code, and change it to `ThenBy`.

Comment: But how to concatenate OrderBy and ThenBy by "."?

Comment: @user585440 I really don't know what you mean. You write an overload the exact same way as the above, but changing to `ThenBy`. Then you can write `source.OrderBy(a => a.Id, true).ThenBy(a => a.name, false);`

Comment: For `ThenBy`, the source type is `IOrderedQueryable`

Answer (score 0):

As I mention in the comments you can create something like this...

```
public static class LinqExtension
{
    public static IOrderedEnumerable<TSource> OrderByAsc<TSource, TKey>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Expression<Func<T, object>> expression)
    {
        IEnumerable<TSource> newEnumerable = source;
        int ctr = 0;
        NewArrayExpression array = expression.Body as NewArrayExpression;
        foreach( object obj in ( IEnumerable<object> )( array.Expressions ) )
        {
             if(ctr == 0)
             newEnumerable = newEnumerable
                .OrderBy(item => item.GetType().GetProperty(obj.ToString()).GetValue(item, null));
             else
             newEnumerable = newEnumerable
                .ThenBy(item => item.GetType().GetProperty(obj.ToString()).GetValue(item, null));
             ctr++;
        }

        return newEnumerable;      
    }

    public static IOrderedEnumerable<TSource> OrderByDesc<TSource, TKey>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Expression<Func<T, object>> expression)
    {
        IEnumerable<TSource> newEnumerable = source;

        NewArrayExpression array = expression.Body as NewArrayExpression;
        int ctr = 0;
        foreach( object obj in ( IEnumerable<object> )( array.Expressions ) )
        {
             if(ctr == 0)
             newEnumerable = newEnumerable
                .OrderByDescending(item => item.GetType().GetProperty(obj.ToString()).GetValue(item, null));
             else
             newEnumerable = newEnumerable
                .ThenByDescending(item => item.GetType().GetProperty(obj.ToString()).GetValue(item, null));
             ctr++;
        }

        return newEnumerable;      
    } 
}
```

And use it like this:

```
using myNameSpace.LinqExtensions;
...

l = l.OrderByAsc(item => new [] { item.Prop1, item.Prop2, item.Prop3});
l = l.OrderByDesc(item => new [] { item.Prop1, item.Prop2, item.Prop3});
```

Of course you can try creating an extension to combine both order by ascending and descending into a single method. Just an idea.

**DISCLAIMER: I wrote this on notepad and haven't tested it due to lack of resources.**